# IE6 - how to overflow div contents outside the div

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have a layout with a header, left nav and right content section.  When right content is too wide to fit in the parent containers (divs), I'd like the content to overflow the div to the right.  This is working in modern browsers as I'd like, but IE6 is preventing the overflow, and subsequently forcing the left navigation below the right content.  Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width:984px;margin:0 auto;">
            <div id="header" style="height:76px;background-color:#69B8E1">Site Header</div>
            <div id="contentWrapper" style="float:right;margin-left:-175px;width:100%">
                <div id="rightContent" style="margin-left:165px;background-color:#C6DDDF;">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                            <th>
                                Very lengthy description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="leftMenu" style="float:left;width:150px;background-color:#C4DF9B">Left 
                Menu</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tryed http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/ie6-how-to-overflow-div-contents-outside-the-div

**UPDATED:**

```
<div id="contentWrapper" style="position:relative;float:right;margin-left:-175px;width:100%">
<div id="rightContent" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;margin-left:165px;background-color:#C6DDDF;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Unfortunately this is an existing layout of a website I'm tweaking.  I don't have the option to modify the placement of the divs (i.e. rightcontent and leftmenu must stay as siblings, in that order).

Comment: Awesome!  I have a few more nested divs in the actual layout, but I think this will send me down the right path.